# Mustache.js: why it breaks string into Object of separate characters

Tags: javascript, mustache

javaScript object being passed to Mustache:

```
data      = {};
data.list = ['title', 'editor'];
data.test = function(){ console.log(this); };
```

Mustache Template

```
{{#list}}
   {{test}}
{{/list}}
```

Output in Console (Chrome):

```
String {0: "t", 1: "i", 2: "t", 3: "l", 4: "e"}
String {0: "e", 1: "d", 2: "i", 3: "t", 4: "o", 5: "r"}
```

Why Mustache breaks strings? Can I stop it? This doesn't let me to do a simple task:

```
$.inArray(this, someArray);
```

The worst thing - that Mustache's String object don't have .join() method so I have no chance as only glue it back by a loop:

```
var str = '';
$.each(this, function(k,v){str += v;});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mustache handles values in an array as objects. You can see that by typing `new String('foo')` in your console. The output is similar to that one you see produced by mustache.

So you need to change your array to contain objects, like:

```
data.list = [ { value: 'title' }, { value: 'editor' } ];
```

And your `{{test}}` accessor:

```
data.test = function(){ console.log(this.value); };
```